# Making In-app Billing Requests with Javascript

Tags: android, android-studio, web-applications

I am developing a webapp for android and I need a way to sell digital contents.

Is there a way to make make In-app Billing Requests with javascript or html5 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add html pages and javascript actions to your Android app using a web view inside the layout of your Activity/Fragment.

If you want to store the html and javascript pages into your app (like all the other java and xml elements) you must save them into an asset folder, and recall its contents through your activity.

See this example to have a better understanding how to link html/javascript actions with java android:
https://github.com/alessandroargentieri/JavaScript-Android